# Setting empty var that will be populated if the form is submitted

Tags: php, postgresql

I am creating drop down box that will filter my postgreSQL table, I need to create a set an empty var that will be populated if the form is submitted but i am having trouble with this.

**Code**

```
<?php
$conn  = pg_connect("host=db.dcs.aber.ac.uk port=5432
                                        dbname=teaching user=csguest password=********");
// set empty var that will be populated if the form is submitted
$where = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['category'])) {
        //  I also need to build a where conditional, but that another question
        $where = " WHERE Category = '" . pg_escape_string($_POST['category']) . "'";
    }
}
$res = pg_query($conn, "SELECT Foodtype, Manufacturer, Description, Price 
                                        FROM food $where
                                        ORDER BY Category ASC");
echo "<table id=\"myTable\" border='1'>";
while ($a = pg_fetch_row($res)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j = 0; $j < pg_num_fields($res); $j++) {
         echo "<td>" . $a[$j] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "<td><form id='cart' name='cart' method='POST'  action='addToBasket.php'>
                                        <input type='submit' name='Select' id='Select' value='Add To Basket'>
                                        </form></td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

$Alcoholic = pg_query("SELECT Foodtype, Manufacturer, 
                                    Description, Price FROM food WHERE      Category = 'Alcoholic'");


?>
```

I am having problems with setting an empty var.

Comment: What problems are you having specifically - does the query fail? Are you getting error messages? Unexpected results?

Comment: Like steve said, what is happening at the moment? Does it completely fail or do you not know how to set an empty var?

Comment: @Steve Im not exactly sure how to go about it, setting up an empty variable that will be filled when the form is submitted. I cannot find any tutorials or examples online.

Comment: @RushFan2112 yeah, i get that. However your code looks to do exactly that. However, since you posted this question, i expect its not working how you want, hence why im asking you to explain what problems you are having TLDR; you code looks fine

Comment: Sorry i did properly read your comment, the problems i'm having is nothing is happening at the moment, no error marks either. Would you like me to update my original question with more code?

Comment: @Steve Sorry i did not* properly read your comment.

Comment: Im not trying to be awkward - you really need to be explicit to make an answerable question. `"nothing is happening"` is just too vague. Does the query run at all? Do you see anything on the page, or just a white screen? Perhaps the query runs as expected, but it doesnt include the where clause, even when you submit the form?

Comment: http://users.aber.ac.uk/sec17/cs25010/database.php Here is a link to the page, as you can see when you press submit on the drop down menu, it does not show only the alcohol, nor does it show any error messages.

Comment: Did you fix it, because it is working fine for me

Comment: Ahh yes, It was mainly due to me not have a method="post" in the drop down menu